# Unable to import QiskitRuntimeService

Tags: python, qiskit

Whenever I try to import `QiskitRuntimeService` as in the following:

```js
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService

service = QiskitRuntimeService()
```

I end up with the following error:

```js
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 2
      1 # Initialize your account
----> 2 from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService
      4 service = QiskitRuntimeService() 
      5 # service.backends()

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\qiskit_ibm_runtime\__init__.py:163
    160 import logging
    161 import warnings
--> 163 from .qiskit_runtime_service import QiskitRuntimeService
    164 from .ibm_backend import IBMBackend
    165 from .runtime_job import RuntimeJob

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\qiskit_ibm_runtime\qiskit_runtime_service.py:32
     26 from qiskit.providers.providerutils import filter_backends
     27 from qiskit.providers.models import (
     28     PulseBackendConfiguration,
     29     QasmBackendConfiguration,
     30 )
---> 32 from qiskit_ibm_runtime import ibm_backend
     33 from .proxies import ProxyConfiguration
     34 from .utils.hgp import to_instance_format, from_instance_format
...
---> 66 from qiskit.primitives.containers.estimator_pub import EstimatorPub
     67 from qiskit.primitives.containers.sampler_pub import SamplerPub
     68 from qiskit.qpy.binary_io.value import _write_parameter, _read_parameter

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit.primitives.containers'
```

I am not sure what modules I need to install to make this work. Has anybody encountered this issue or something like it?

Thanks